# How to make a POST request to the Windows phone 7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, httpwebrequest, http-post

How to send data to authenticate to the server? Using the current code:

```
WebClient MyWebClient = new WebClient();
        MyWebClient.OpenWriteCompleted += new OpenWriteCompletedEventHandler(MyWebClient_OpenWriteCompleted);
        MyWebClient.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; ICS)";
        MyWebClient.OpenWriteAsync(new Uri("http://myserver.com/login"), "POST", "email=myemail@server.com&pass=mypassword");


    void MyWebClient_OpenWriteCompleted(object sender, OpenWriteCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

After this code, if a program-sniffer (HttpAnalyzer) look at Headers and Response Content, in Response Content will be written: `Request is not completed. waiting ...`, and Response Headers will be empty ...
How to make a Post request?

Comment: Have a look at this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8052434/post-requests-on-wp7/8052527#8052527

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Making a POST request using WebClient.


Function()
{    
  WebClient wc = new WebClient();

  var URI = new Uri("http://your_uri_goes_here");
```

//If any encoding is needed.

```
  wc.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
```

//Or any other encoding type.

//If any key needed

```
  wc.Headers["KEY"] = "Your_Key_Goes_Here";

 wc.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_UploadStringCompleted);

 wc.UploadStringAsync(URI,"POST","Data_To_Be_sent");
```

}

```
void wc__UploadStringCompleted(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)

{  

  try            
  {          
     MessageBox.Show(e.Result);
```

//e.result fetches you the response against your POST request.

```
 }

  catch(Exception exc)         
  {             
     MessageBox.Show(exc.ToString());            
  }

}
```

Comment: wc_cart_session.UploadStringAsync(URI,"POST","Data_To_Be_sent");    
This line gives an error. Are you sure it shouldnt be :
 wc.UploadStringAsync(URI,"POST","Data_To_Be_sent");

Answer (score 1):

According to [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144219.aspx), contents are actually sent when you close the stream passed to you in the argument of `OpenWriteCompleted` event.

Since you don't close the stream properly, it doesn't send anything.

Comment: Could you show an example of how close the stream properly, please?

Comment: You close a stream with steam.Close(). The MSDN documentation is your friend.